# How does Qt Designer work in terms of creating more than 1 dialog per file?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm starting to use Qt Designer.

I am trying to create a game, and the first task that I want to do is to create a window where you have to input the name of the map that you want to load. If the map exists, I then switch to the main game window, and if the name of the map doesn't exist, I want to display a popup window that tells the user that the name of the map they wrote is not valid.

I'm a bit confused with the part of showing the "not valid" pop-up window.

I realized that I have two options:

- Creating 2 separated .ui files, and with the help of the .show() and .hide() commands show the correspoding window if the user input is invalid.
- The other option that I'm thinking of creating both windows in the same .ui file, which seems to be a better option, but I don't really know how to work with windows that come from the same file. Should I create a separate class for each of the windows that come from the Qt Designer file? If not, how can I access both windows from the same class?

Comment: Oh and btw doing what you outlined is quite feasible within pyqt5 especially if you have coded your UIs properly which means you did not use the Designer

Comment: I am a Qt Designer lover :-) and I don't agree with DennisJensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option seems impossible, it would be great to share the .ui since in my years that I have worked with Qt Designer I have not been able to implement what you point out.

An .ui is an XML file that describes the elements and their properties that will be used to create a class that is used to fill a particular widget. So considering the above, your second option is impossible.

This concludes that the only viable option is its first method.